# Unable to start Tor browser using an account other than the one it was installed with (Windows 7)

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, help

I have just installed Tor Browser package (Windows), using my admin account (installation failed with a normal account due to insufficient privileges. I am able to start the Tor browser ok with the admin account. However, when I switch to my regular non admin account and try to start the Tor browser, I get that error message that says Firefox is already running. I have attempted to fix this particular problem from Mozilla help, but they just don't work. (There is a firefox profile lock file that needs to be deleted; I did this and it made no difference). So can you only run Tor browser from the same account that you install it in? If this is the case, then I'll need to un-install and then re-run the installer from an elevated command prompt, however, I tried to un-install Tor-Broswer, but I can't find an un-installer, and the Tor Browser doesn't appear in the application install list (appwiz.cpl).

Please assist if you can,
thanks.

Comment: Where did you install it to?
Also there is no uninstaller, just delete the folder. The bundle .exe is just a compressed archive that simply unpacks itself to the destination set.

Make sure you install it to a folder that all users has permission to use and access. What you mention is very typical for when you install it and windows 'locks' it because it's only enabled through administrator access.

Comment: Thanks for that. I just moved the folder to the public user profile. Tor Brower now works fine from the non admin account. It must have failed the first time because originally I put it in program files, which needs admin access, for write operations which I assume is necessary for Tor to run.

Comment: Move the Tor folder to C root or some other folder without user attachment.

Answer (score 8):

A solution that doesn't break all your shortcuts:

- Right-click the `Tor Browser` folder *(which you probably installed to `Program Files`)*
- Properties --> Security --> (Your username) --> Edit --> (Your username) --> Allow full control

Comment: Nice and easy solution!

Comment: Working for me at windows 10 x64

Comment: If the user that needs access does not appear in the list, you may need to click Edit -> Add and then enter the username.

Comment: The other solution is better because it follows principle of least privilege for increased security and data integrity. Depending on the situation, it may not be desirable to give users full control because they can modify permissions. Read, write, and modify is what most people really actually are trying to achieve when they choose full control. I used to think  the same thing that it gives full read and write, but didn't realize that it in fact also allows changes to permissions.

Answer (score 4):

This was caused by the fact that the Tor Browser was running from Program Files. It would have been useful in the help to say that the Tor Browser bundle should be copied to a location with write access. Non admin accounts can't write to Program Files, which is why it failed. I just copied to /User/Public, and all is fine.

Answer (score 3):

Strictly speaking, the only folder you need to open up access to is

> %installfolder%\Browser\TorBrowser\Data

That's where the caches and profile information is kept. No need to open up security on directories you don't need to.

Comment: The only folder I've changed and got a feedback! But that worked out for me using Debian installation of Tor.

Comment: This worked well for me on Windows 10. This should be the number one answer because it follows the sound security principle of least privilege by only giving access to modify what is needed and no more. If possible, it is best that non-admins do not have write access to the rest of the program files because this could allow a user or program to modify executable files that they should not.